# React: how to pass props through a Link from react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, router

I'm trying to pass `title` from props to my `Dishes` component using `<Link>` but can't find a solution. Any sugestions?

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Category = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <Link to="/dishes">
      {title}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Category;
```

`App.js` is looking like this:

```
return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={(props) => (
              <Categories recipes={recipes} />
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/dishes" component={Dishes} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

Comment: Take a look at params in react-router-dom. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object) can pass a state object that can be retrieved from you component through location:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Category = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={{ pathname: "/dishes", state: { title } }}>
      {title}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Category;
```

Then you can extract `state` from `location` prop. But since you are passing this value only when you click on `Link`, `state` can be **undefined** if you access the `Route` directly. This way you may want to provide a `defaultValue` in these cases:

```
const Dishes = ({location}) => {
  const { title = 'defaultValue' } = location.state || {}

  return <div>{title}</div>
}
```

Comment: This worked! There's just a curly bracket missing in the link tag. This should do: <Link to={{ pathname: "/dishes", state: { title }}}>